# image tweet is showing in view summary on twitter

Tags: jquery, twitter, tweets, share-button

I am implementing twitter sharing on my website. I have added the meta tag of the page and twitter card validation is validating the url. and i am implementing the twitter sharing button to share my content with image. But once i shared it, twitter is showing the content upfront and image after clicking on view summary. I want my image to show with the content upfront on my wall. what to do?

here is my sharing button

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="cityseekr" data-related="cityseekr" data-hashtags="cityseekr" data-dnt="true">Tweet</a>
```

and meta tag read like this:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@mySite" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@mycreator" />
<meta property="og:url" content="my url" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="my description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="myImage.jpg" />
```

and this is my jquery

```
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        t._e = [];
        t.ready = function(f) {
           t._e.push(f);
        };
    return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

first of all, i am not sure if this the correct way to implement share for the requirement and if it is correct then what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Sometimes robot.txt files of site disallow twitter bots, check it

Answer (score 0):

From [Discussion](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-cards-validated-and-preview-ok-but-photos-not-are-pre-expanded/25702)

I assume the twitter image from `og:image` is not expanded by **default**, for showing it upfront the tweet has to be either promoted /paid or the image need to be hosted on Twitter's site, else your image wont be expanded by default.

Comment: thanks for sharing this.. little disappointment. Is there no way to implement this.

Comment: Nope Its seems, try to reduce your image dimension, give it a try